# KDE Plasma's widgets look comically large when using two screens

Tags: debian, kde, display, xrandr

So, if I boot with only one screen or use cinnamon or another desktop environment, everything looks nice, but if i boot with two screens, it looks like this:

[image]

Notice how everything looks normal in the browser, however the task bar and widgets look insanely large. I suspect they are being scaled as if both screens are actually one, so it would make sense to be this big.

```
Xrandr gives me:



 Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
    DVI-D-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
       1360x768      60.02 +
       1920x1080     60.00*   59.94    29.97    23.98    60.05    60.00  
       1280x720      60.00    59.94  
       1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
       800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
       720x480       59.94  
       640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
    HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
       1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
       1680x1050     59.95  
       1600x900      60.00  
       1440x900      59.89  
       1400x1050     59.98  
       1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
       1280x800      59.81  
       1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
       1152x864      75.00  
       1024x768      75.03    60.00  
       800x600       75.00    60.32  
       720x576       50.00  
       720x480       59.94  
       640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
    DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

So it seems that the resolution IS correct.

How can I fix this?

This is how it looks if i boot with a single display, and then connect the second one after KDE has already loaded

[image]

Comment: https://bugs.kde.org maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me forever and many days of figuring out the problem. It turns out my DVI monitor has a broken EDID, so it was telling my PC that it's display size is significantly smaller than it actually is, while maintaining the resolution, which created this huge DPI difference. I'm not exactly sure what exactly fixed it, but something did. Here's what I did:

I wanted to pass my own EDID file to the computer.

I first got the wrong EDID file. In order to do this, I used the NVIDIA settings tool. I saved it to a temporary folder.

I then followed [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/synaptiko/b59d814ea07186a9a9f210724930f2ca) to correct the EDID file. In specific:

I opened the wrong edid file using an HEX editor. The display size lives on offset 0x15 and 0x16 (width vs height respectively) of the binary file. These calculations are in cm, that means that 160mm = 16 cm = 0x10 and 90 mm = 9cm = 0x09. I corrected them manually and saved them to a different place. However, these have different checksums, so we need to fix that.

I ran

```
edid-checksum.py < correct-edid.bin
```

, which told me where to fix the edid (You need to fix checksum on offset 0x7f. ox75 is BAD, should be 0x65). Then i opened the file using a HEX Editor again, updated the value to what is supposed to be correct and saved it. Running the following command

```
parse-edid < dvi-d.bin
```

showed me that the checksum was indeed correct. Now: Here I did two different things and I have no idea what solved it:

First I ran nvidia-xconfig --custom-edid="DVI-D-0:/path/to/correct/edid.bin" which added the edid to my xorg.conf file on /etc/X11.

Then I also updated it on the Kernel side. In order to do that, I saved the correct edid on /lib/firmware/edid/DVI.bin, then I went to /etc/default and added the following to /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet drm.edid_firmware=DVI-D-0:edid/DVI.bin"
```

I then updated the kernel bootloader using

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and restarted the computer. Somehow, it still doesn't work on GNOME, but on Plasma, everything looks fine, so that's a plus.

**UPDATE:**

I had been using gdm3, and it worked out fine after the solution given above. Today I tried switching to sddm and everything failed again. I don't really have time to chase this bug, so if anyone is having the same problem, and the solution above STILL doesn't seem to work, then try: *sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3*